# Data Scraping For an Android App from a local HTML Page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to data scrape information for a timetable application for android. The html looks like this:

```
      <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:00</font></td>     
      <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:15</font></td>
      <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:30</font></td>
```

And also like this:

```
     <td align='left'><font color='#FF0000'>Mobility</font></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
     <col align='left' />
     <col align='right' />
     <tr>
     <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>P2016</font></td>
     <td align='right'><font color='#008000'>E.Palin</font></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
     <col align='left' />
     <tr>
     <td align='left'><font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

I am using java and jsoup in android studio and i was wondering how would i, code wise, go about scraping this so that i can get the different times and "Mobility" "P2016" "E.Palin" and "22-29, 32-36" to appear in my application?

Answer (score 1):

First, your HTML is not welled formed or it is just a sample ?

With [Estivate](https://github.com/btheu/estivate/) you could write JSoup query this way:

```
    File input = new File("C:\\path\\to\\html.html");

    Document document= Jsoup.parse(input , "UTF-8", "/");

    EstivateMapper mapper = new EstivateMapper();
    Result result = mapper.map(document, Result.class);
```

With Result class as :

```
    public class Result {

       @Text(select = "font:matchesOwn(.*:.*)")
       public List<String> times;

       @Text(select = "font:not(:matchesOwn(.*:.*))")
       public List<String> others;

    }
```

You'll get 2 lists : 
times=[9:00, 9:15, 9:30], others=[Mobility, P2016, E.Palin, 22-29, 32-36]

Comment: The HTML is just a sample of a larger file, I will look into Estivate

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JavaApplication22 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File input = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\html.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");        
    Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");

    for (Element td: tableElements){
        System.out.println(td.text());
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Theres a error with "Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");" Unhandled error, java.io.IOException. any clues?

Comment: IOException is checked exception, which either need to be catch (or) re-throw. Add throws IOException like i do in my main method or catch by surround block with try-catch

Comment: [Exeption tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Answer (score 0):

jsoup elements support a CSS (or jquery) like selector syntax to find matching elements

The select method is available in a Document, Element, or in Elements and returns a list of Elements.

Examples

find elements by tag, e.g. td           doc.select("td");

find elements by ID, e.g. #logo       doc.select("#logo");

find elements by class name, e.g. .masthead doc.select("div.masthead").first();

elements with attribute, e.g. [href]        doc.select("a[href]");

```
try {
        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\manna\\Desktop\\html.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
        Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");
        for (Element td: tableElements){
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```